# Prompt for client certificates for selected url's on IHS Server

Tags: java, ibmhttpserver

We have a server that prompts for a client certificate when accessed.

How do we configure it to only prompt for a certificate for selected url's? For example, when accessing [this](http://www.myserver.com/protected_area) a certificate should be provided, but for [this](http://www.myserver.com/unprotected_area) it should not.

This does not work for me on our `IBM HTTP server`!

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not supported in IHS. You either have to use a separate IP:PORT combination for this protected area or prompt use `SSLClientAuth OPTIONAL` to prompt for the enitre virtual host then limit access to /protected_area by checking with e.g. mod_rewrite to see if a certificate was provided.

```
<virtualhost *:443>
  SSLEnable
  SSLClientAuth OPTIONAL
  ...
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{ENV:SSL_CLIENT_CERTBODYLEN} ^$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error/
  RewriteRule /protected_area/ /certrequired.html [PT]
</virtualhost>
```